# Customizing password reset mail View in Laravel

Tags: email, laravel

How can I change what appears in the password reset email in laravel?
Like addressing the user with his name and show the password reset link etc.
Where is that email view located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can change the email template, which is located at

```
 resources/views/emails/password.blade.php.
```

For customization pass an instance of User model to this view and echo out user name there like:

```
Hello, {{$user->username}}
//And Body of Reset link goes here
```

### Update for laravel 5.3+

In updated laravel versions the code structure is revamped.
Password reset mail is now at *vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php*

and its corresponding template is at:
*resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php*

So in order to customize it, you may need to:

- Copy it to somewhere in your app's directory.
- Set the proper namespace to refer to it.
- Add a new method to User class & reference it to newly copied class
- Customize.

Comment: but how do I tell the notifications (or at least the reset email notification) to use that template ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales you're probably working in Laravel 5.3 so check my new answer for a proper way to change the mail content.

Comment: It's still unclear to really change the template, i.e. use a custom template (OUTSIDE vendor, of course)

Answer (score 6):

In Laravel 5.3 they changed the entire password reset code, so the given answer doesn't work anymore.

If you want to change the basic texts you should copy vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php to some place in your own app (e.g. app/Notifications/ResetPassword.php), set the correct namespace and alter the texts as you wish. (don't alter the original ResetPassword.php since it's bad practice to alter files in the vendor folder!)

Then add a `sendPasswordResetNotification` method to the User class and make sure to reference to the appropriate ResetPassword class:

```
use App\Notifications\ResetPassword;

...

public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token) {
    $this->notify(new ResetPassword($token));
}
```

If you want to change the rest of the mail template (which is used for all other mails as well) do the following:

Run `php artisan vendor:publish`

This will copy some blades from the vendor folder to the resources/views/vendor
The resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php is the one you want to change.

Hope this helps for people who got stuck in Laravel 5.3

Comment: How we can access the $user object in the new notification email view template let say we want user full name if i do {{$user->fullname}} it gives me error.

Comment: In the ResetPassword class the user is given to the toMail function (by the name of $notifiable in this case): `public function toMail($notifiable) { ... $notifiable->fullname ... }`
Depending on your exact implementation you should be abled to implement it from there into your mail template. Could look something like this:
`$MailMessage->greeting(trans('mail.passResetGreeting', ['name' => $notifiable->fullname]) );`

Comment: Great answer, thank you. However I would not recomment to publish the complete vendor directory. Only notifications are needed, so try `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications`

Comment: Changing a view in the vendor file does not seem to make sense

Comment: @IceFire Not sure why you downvote; `php artisan vendor:publish` will take the files out of the vendor and into your own code, so you are not actually changing the content in the vendor files. This is how Laravel intended it to work.

Comment: Not for me. A aubdirectory “vendor” is created under public that will be overwritten with each publish. The idea should be to point to some file outside of public/vendor to be robust against publish. This is possible but not conveyed in your answer

Comment: When you do it this way noting will be overwritten after an update or publish. You basically create a copy of what's in Laravel by default.