# Laravel 5.1 user name in forget password email template

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5.1 with *out of the box* authentication.

In the 'password reset email', sent to the user, I want to add `username`, so that the user receives the email personalized with his/her name.

Any guidance on how to do this is appreciated.

Comment: still I only know, we have to add a username variable in views/emails/password.blde.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referecing this SO post: [Customizing password reset mail View in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498685/customizing-password-reset-mail-view-in-laravel)

> Yes you can change the email template, which is located at:
>
> `resources/views/emails/password.blade.php`
>
> For customization, pass an instance of User model to this view and echo
>   out username per the following:
>
> `Hello, {{$user->username}}`
>   `//And Body of Reset link goes here`

Comment: thx, I tried it but it add nothing. Don't we need to override the PasswordController.php in App/Http/Controller/Auth ?

Comment: oh thanks @HappyCoding, it is working, There was a different fieldname for name in db. cheerz

Comment: @qammarferoz, what was the field name? I would like to update my answer with the correct field name.

Comment: It was a custom field name, we were using first_name. that was not default.